# Google Sheets Paste Value & Format but no Formula

Tags: google-sheets

We are looking to **only** remove formulas from cells in Google Sheet, keeping both the values and the formatting. It seems this may not be possible? Pasting values only loses the formatting. Pasting format only does not remove the formulas. Is it possible to replace formulas with values **while keeping formatting**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that I can (i) Paste Special > Values Only, and then (ii) copy & paste formatting from another column (that has the formatting) onto the column with values only. Would be nice to have a single button for this, but I can confirm that it can be done w/ these two steps.